Flutter Gemini API File Usage
I want to make a chatbot by using GEMINI API for a fund advisor in flutter but  i want to make Gemini read that xlsx file and respond me by reading that. But I failed always. There are instances at python or javascript but i cant find it for flutter
void _sendMessage() async {
    try {
      final messageText = _controller.text.trim();
      if (messageText.isEmpty) return;
      _controller.clear();
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(Message(text: messageText, isUser: true));
        _isLoading = true; // Set loading state when sending message
      });
      _scrollToBottom();
      final model = GenerativeModel(
          model: 'gemini-pro',
          apiKey: 'API-KEY');
      final content = [Content.text(messageText)];
      final response = await model.generateContent(content);

      setState(() {
        _messages.add(Message(text: response.text!, isUser: false));
        _isLoading = false; // Clear loading state after receiving response
      });
      _scrollToBottom();
      _controller.clear();
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error : $e");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false; // Ensure loading state is cleared on error
      });
    }
  }

thats my message code im sending gemini messages and getting responds from here and I tried file reading by that code
 final geminiApi = GeminiApi('API-KEY');
      const filePath = 'assets/data.xlsx';
      const mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet';

      // Upload the file
      final fileResponse = await geminiApi.uploadFile(filePath, mimeType);
      final fileId = fileResponse['id'];

      // Wait for the file to be processed
      await geminiApi.waitForFileProcessing(fileId);

thats for i tried make it read from that code but it didnt work

silly point but.. have you asked Gemini? Feed it the javascript code and ask if it can help you create a dart/flutter version? It's very good at that akshully... ;)

i tried that but it didnt help me actually and i started to think for flutter there is no way to do that.
